# Join de atributos

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

[![Estoy haciendo un coordinator (api). El metodo call se encargaria de realizar una lista de aeropuertos (tanto departure como arrival) dado un determinado pais. Si alguien pudiese orientarme lo agradezco. El error es el siguiente   1) Countries::GetFlightCoordinator is expected to include "2"
Failure/Error: expect(coordinator.call).to include(country_id)

```
 ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError:
   Can't join 'Country' to association named 'arrival_airport_id'; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpZPb.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpZPb.png)

Comment: Pon el código, no intentes poner imágenes. Te recomiendo que mires [ask] y el [tour] de bienvenida

Comment: Lo intentare, muchas gracias!